# Работа с mysql,создание связной таблицы

Tags: mysql

Как сделать такую таблицу? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался, но результат не тот

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS theme;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS votesres;

    CREATE TABLE votesres (
      id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      yes int,
      no int
    ) ENGINE InnoDB;




    CREATE TABLE theme (
      themeid  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name     varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
      votes    INT ,
      FOREIGN KEY (votes) REFERENCES votesres (id)
    ) ENGINE InnoDB;



    INSERT INTO theme (name)
         VALUES ('sd');

    INSERT INTO votesres(yes) VALUES (2);
    INSERT INTO votesres(no) VALUES (2);

    select * from theme;
```

Comment: Зачем вы усложняете себе жизнь? В вашем варианте для извлечения информации вам понадобиться делать JOIN. К тому же `votesres.id` должен быть не автоикрементальным и внешним ключем к `themeid`. Потому что у вас связь 1 к 1.  В вашем случае достаточно сделать колонки `votes_yes` и `votes_no` в таблице `theme`

Comment: Как уже сказали выше в данном случае колонки yes и no надо хранить в самой таблице theme, Такая структура как сейчас понадобилась бы, если бы у вас могло быть более 1 (в том числе и 10 и более) theme для которых действительна одна и та же запись votesres. Что же касается объявлений foreign key, то они нужны БД только для поддержания ссылочной целостности, что бы в theme невозможно было записать в votes значение, для которого нет записи в votesres. И нельзя было удалить запись из votesres на которую ссылаются.

Comment: А любой вывод данных вы описываете сами. Наличие ключей никак не влияет на `select *` из одной таблицы, он всегда дает данные только одной таблицы. Для вывода данных из нескольких таблиц используются немного более сложные запросы. В вашем случае вы сами указываете в запросе join с другой таблицей и указываете условия их объединения (ключи и в данном случае БД смотреть не будет). И кроме всего прочего вы в theme при вставке записи не указали значение для поля votes, так что там сейчас NULL и запись никак не связана с таблицей votesres. Тем более что в нее вы вставили 2 записи (2,NULL), (NULL,2)